# Drag and drop app icon into my widget - Android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, widget, homescreen

I am curious if it's possible to make an Android home screen widget that can have app icons dropped on it? For example, say my widget is a 2x2(spaces) box on the home screen. Then a user drags and drops the app icon shortcut from another app onto my widget. Would it be possible to then recognize the dropped app icons package name or other related info?

I have researched this on my own and cannot find any way of doing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not even possible. Widget API that provides Android doesn't allow that. Just to be clear where is only few opportunities that allow RemoteViews and Widget to do. So your usecase impossible to do.